# From the recent Spider-Man films which characters are owned by Sony?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe

With the news that Sony and Disney have failed to reach an agreement about the next set of movies I wondered what this means for the ancillary Spider-Man characters that have become a part of the recent movies.

I know that Happy, Nick Fury and Maria are owned by Disney and so will probably no longer be in Spider-Man films, as are the other Avengers.

But of the other characters that appeared in the movies, which are owned by Sony? For example Vulture, Scorpion, Mysterio and others. Which do Sony own the rights to, and which where loaned to them as part of the deal with Disney?

Answer (score 7):

As far as I'm aware, and it's the short answer, Spider-Man and all of the supporting/auxiliary characters are owned by Sony so that includes: Aunt May, Uncle Ben, Mary Jane, Ned Leeds, Vulture, Mysterio, etc. This graph that has been shared around various places over time seems to visualise it quite well.

[image: Graph showing who owns what character]

Of course things have changed a bit since then as Mysterio was up until a few days ago shared with Marvel like Spider-Man but the graph just shows him as a Sony only character. Now of course the overlap is gone unless a new deal can be made between the two companies.

Comment: I'm trying to find something a bit more official than this graph but it provides a nice visual whilst I do so.

Comment: The nature of the Universal overlap is different to the Spider-Man overlap. This chart isn't well labelled.